# Cannot open include file: 'linmath.h'

Tags: c++, glfw

I have set up GLFW and GLAD in Visual Studio 2017 as follows:
I created in C: directory, folder GLFW-GLAD, and in V.S., Empty Project "Project-0" and Source file "Main.cpp".
1. In project GLFW-GLAD's "Properties", Configuration: [All Configurations], Platform: [Active(Win32)], Configuration Properties:
1.1. C/C++ > General > "Additional Include Directories" window  > "C:\GLFW-GLAD\glfw\include" and "C:\GLFW-GLAD\glad\include".
1.2. Linker > General > "Additional Library Directories" window > "C:\GLFW-GLAD\glfw\lib-vc2015"
1.3. Linker > Input > "Additional Dependencies" window > "opengl32.lib; glfw3.lib; glfw3dll.lib".
1.4. Linker > System > Subsystem > Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)
2. In project folder "Project-0" I have pasted files: "glad.c" and "glfw3.dll".
I copied program from https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html and pasted in Main.cpp code area. I attempted run it but failed. Output is
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'linmath.h': No such file or directory"
Please help.

Comment: Is there any such file on your system? Where is it?

Comment: Exactly, your job as a programmer is to figure out why the compiler can not find the file in it's include paths. We don't know what is on your disk so its difficult to help..

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to grab the .h file from here and put it somewhere the compiler can see it. https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to project (by Solution Explorer > Source Files > Add > New Item > Header File) header file linmath.h. Go to https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/deps/linmath.h copy code and paste in linmath.h code area.
2. Delete glad.c from project folder and add it to project by Solution Explorer > Source Files > Add > Existing Item. Regards.